# Filtering out rows with children in Elasticsearch Nest

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest

I have a type `PurchaseOrder` which can have 0 or many `VendorStatuses`. I want to create a filter that will find `PurchaseOrders` that have **no** `VendorStatuses`. How can I do this?

Things I've tried:

```
Filter &= Filter<PurchaseOrder>.HasChild<PoVendorStatus>(c => c
    .MaxChildren(0)); //40 results

Filter &= Filter<PurchaseOrder>.HasChild<PoVendorStatus>(c => c
    .MaxChildren(0)
    .Query(x => x.MatchAll())); // 0 results

Filter &= Filter<PurchaseOrder>.Missing(y => y.VendorStatuses); // 40 results

Filter &= Filter<PurchaseOrder>.Exists(y => y.VendorStatuses); // 0 results

Filter &= Filter<PurchaseOrder>.Nested(nfd => nfd.Path(x => x.VendorStatuses.First())
    .Filter(f2 => f2.Missing(y => y.Id))); 
//9 results! But these are the ones that *have* statuses, I need the opposite

Filter &= Filter<PurchaseOrder>.Nested(nfd => nfd.Path(x => x.VendorStatuses.First())
    .Filter(f2 => f2.Exists(y => y.Id))); 
//0 results >:(

Filter &= Filter<PurchaseOrder>.Nested(nfd => nfd.Path(x => x.VendorStatuses)
    .Query(f2 => f2.Terms(t => t.VendorStatuses.First().Id, new[] { (long?)null })));
//40 results

Filter &= Filter<PurchaseOrder>.Nested(nfd => nfd.Path(x => x.VendorStatuses)
    .Query(f2 => f2.Term(t => t.VendorStatuses.First().Id, null)));
//40 results
```

There are 40 records in the index, and I know there's at least one that has no vendor statuses, but these queries are returning all or nothing. How can I implement this?

We are using Nest 1.7.2 and Elasticsearch version 1.4.5

Answer (score 0):

A colleague found a way to do this. We found that if we negate the filter that returned all the records that DO have statuses, it worked. I didn't realize you could simply negate filters like that.

```
Filter &= !Filter<PurchaseOrder>.Nested(nfd => nfd.Path(x => x.VendorStatuses.First())
     .Filter(f2 => f2.Missing(y => y.Id)));
```

Comment: NEST overloads the `&`, `|` and `!` operators on `FilterContainer` and `QueryContainer` to make conjunctions, disjunctions and negation of queries and filters easier. In 2.x, the `+` unary operator is also overloaded to wrap a querie in a `bool` query `filter` clause.

Comment: I knew they overloaded `&` and `|` but i couldn't see that `!` was overridden, so i hadn't tried it